# PDO Not working in php on wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I am facing difficulty getting data into my database using PDO. The insertion works when I use `mysql_connect`/`mysql_query` though, so I am sure it's something about PDO I am not getting right:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXXXX","root","");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try{
    $query= "INSERT INTO tableC VALUES ('1111','2222','XX YY','ERTY','33');";
    $result = $conn ->prepare($query);
    $result ->execute();
} catch {
    echo "PDO error:" . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Couple of points: I am using PHP  and connecting to WAMP server. PHP version is 5.3.13. I have also checked that my query works.

Comment: Is there any exception? HAve you enabled pdo extension?

Comment: Note that you have a syntax error (`$exception` is not defined). Please refer to http://fr2.php.net/exceptions

Comment: Please supply any errors you are getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `$conn->` where as you are using `$db` for connection so the below snippet

```
$conn ->prepare($query);
```

Should be written as

```
$db->prepare($query);
```

---

Also, where did you got `$exception` from? Your `catch` statement should look like

```
catch(PDOException $exception) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue that you are not storing the exception

Replace your catch line with the following

```
} catch (Exception $exception) {
```